# What are the default search directories to link a library on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, deployment, linker, shared-libraries, osx-leopard

I've build the [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) with CMake on Mac OS X and get two shared libraries: *libgtest.dylib* and *libgtest_main.dylib*. And now I need install both them. I know there are some default search directories on Linux, such as **/usr/lib**, **/usr/local/lib**, etc.. But I am unfamiliar with Mac OS X and don't know where to place those libraries.

In [Mac OS X Directory Structure](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/30/mac-os-x-directory-structure-explained/), I find there are three directories of libraries: **~/Library**, **/Library** and **/usr/lib**. And I've tried to place gtest libraries into these directories respectively  and found out only **/usr/lib** works.

What I want to know is wether there are some rules about the default search directories on **Mac OS X** just like on Linux and Windows.

Comment: I'm wondering why the word "libgtest_main.dylib" have not italic effect as I have enter ``*`` before and after it.

Comment: I voted the question up. Because this is a thing that is so often done wrong, it pains me. See my comment to the answer of aponomarenko below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the default values for environment variables used by the [dyld](https://web.archive.org/web/20180102020805/https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) linker:

> DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
>    **...**
> By default, it is set to
> **$(HOME)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib**

[This](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html) article about "Deploying an Application on Mac OS X" and [other](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Deploying_Your_Application#Mac_OS_X_installers) article about "Mac OS X installers" may also help.

Comment: You certainly don't deploy a library in a "non user directory" like /lib etc. Usually a Mac application is bundled into an AppName.app directory. Nothing prevents you from puting your libs into it ;D The two links are quite good.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @linuxbuild's answer, I've found the article ["Dynamic Library Programming Topics > The Library Search Process"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryUsageGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001928-SW21) from Apple's Developer archive helpful. It explains that the search order differs for `libname.dylib` and `path/to/libname.dylib`.

> When the library name is a filename (not a path with directory names), the dynamic loader searches for the library in the following order:
>
> 1. $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> 2. $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
> 3. The process’s working directory
> 4. $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> When the library name contains at least one directory name (a relative or fully qualified pathname), the dynamic loader searches for the library in the following order:
>
> 1. $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH using the filename
> 2. The given pathname
> 3. $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH using the filename