# How to use lapack in C++ on Macbook air

Tags: c++, macos, lapack

I have installed lapack,blas and fftw package on my Mac using Macport.
Where can I find these libraries? What do I need to specify to link these libraries in a C++ program?  Thanks.

Comment: The [LAPACKE](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html) interface will allow you to easily call lapack functions from C++. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285587/what-are-the-default-search-directories-to-link-a-library-on-mac-os-x and take a look at `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib`!

Comment: @francis Great answer. Thanks.